# Magento + Paypal - order status stuck at "Payment review"

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7, paypal-sandbox

I am currently testing the PayPal functionality. I added all the appropriate config information, and the purchase is working perfectly.

Going into the admin panel, all the orders have **"Payment review"** status (they were made either today or yesterday).

My question is - is it normal to last this long ? If it is, how am I supposed to properly test. If it's not, can anyone give me any tips on how to debug this issue ?

Any information on how the process goes from this point on would be highly appreciated. Anticipated thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the PayPal account that you made the purchases on.  Do they show completed in there, or do they say pending?  If they show completed, it may be possible you did not receive the IPN to update your cart.  If they show under review in your test sandbox account, you may have payment review turned on.  You could need to go into the details of the transaction within your test sandbox account and manually accept the payment.  You can also turn payment review off if it is on.  You just need to log into your developer account at developer.paypal.com, click on test accounts.  You then should see a column for payment review.  If it is enabled, you will just need to toggle it from here.

Comment: It seems that for some reason the IPN was not sent. After fiddling with some profile settings it worked. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Since this is quite popular with Google I will add my solution here as well:

I had noticed that many payments would still have the "Payment review" status even after I disabled payment review in my sandbox account.

Turns out that if a payment is made in another than the sandbox account's default currency, it is automatically put into the "Review" status.

To turn this feature off, log into your sandbox account under https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and go to *Profile -> More Options -> Payment Receiving Preferences*. There you can change the setting for "*Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold*" to auto-accept such payments.

Comment: Thank you. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: +1 Thanks indeed. This one should have more up votes since it's essential to get it working when working with multiple currencies.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was transaction status said "Paid" in merchant test (Sandbox) account but IPN response I received had payment status "Pending".

For a new user like me, it was hard to find out how to accept a payment manually when "payment review" is turned on. It took hours for me.

To make it easier for others,
Go to transaction detail -> Click on "More Information" link. Go to bottom of the page. Here you will find "Accept" link just above "Return to My Account" button. Click on "Accept" link and transaction status will change to "Complete".

After that I received IPN response with payment status "Completed"

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This query solved it for me in case of Amazon Sandbox orders which left opened transactions. These popped up in the error log with

> The OrderReferenceId XYZ is invalid

each time with Magento's cron scheduler. Basically the same as for Paypal and all other external payment methods which have a sandbox mode:

```
UPDATE `sales_payment_transaction`
SET `is_closed`=1
WHERE 'S02-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX' IN (txn_id, parent_txn_id);
```